# Spring Boot with Control-M

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, control-m

I am starting to read about **Control-M** batch automation and am unfamiliar with it at this moment.  I have been asked to investigate if Control-M can be integrated into a **Spring Boot REST API**.

Based on my readings, I find this confusing.  All I am finding is that **Control-M** can be integrated to work with **Spring Batch**, but **not with Spring Boot REST APIs**.

It also makes no sense to me to integrate batch processing with API handling requests and responses.  It seam to be a not good idea have these two complete for resources and processing power.

Has anyone done this before and what are your recommendations?

**UPDATE**

My initial understanding was that Control-M will be integrated into the REST API written in Spring Boot. This was false assumption for my case.

Instead, another (Spring Batch) application was created and Control-M would initiate its endpoints to handle processing.

Answer (score 1):

Its a confusing question because APIs, especially REST apis, are designed to be independant of programming language.  If you want, you can execute them from a browser.  Asking if one language or java library supports REST apis vs another language or java library makes little sense.  If Control-M supports REST Apis, then yes, you can use spring boot to execute those rest requests.  You just have to [know spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

As for the main question, does Control-M support REST requests?  Yes, according to [this documentation](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/automation-api/9/services-783052930.html#Services-REST_API_Ref), it does.

Comment: Thanks but I am not asking if one language supports REST.  Not sure where did you get that from.  Thanks for the answer on Control-M REST support though

Answer (score 0):

If you asked how to request REST then you can create a 'Web Services' job or a common CMD job with the 'curl' command.